# If each of X, Y and (X-Y) is a prime number less than 50, how may possible values can X assume?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question :-** If each of X, Y and (X-Y) is a prime number less than 50, how may possible values can X assume ?

**My approach:-**

I listed all the primes numbers 2 to 47 , and then checked for each pair, but this took me a lot of time , is there any efficient way to do it ? some kind of property of prime numbers which I am missing and could reduce my checking for the desired cases ?

I know that a prime number (other than 2,3) can be written in the form of 6k+1, 6k-1 form , can this be used ?

Comment: Well, if $X,Y$ are both odd then we know what $X-Y$ must be, right?

Comment: If X, Y both are odd , then X-Y must be even

Comment: How many even prime numbers are there?

Comment: And if $X$ and $X-Y$ are both odd, then $Y$ must be even. And now we've covered all the cases.

Comment: @lulu, so my Case 1 would be when both  X and Y are odd, then I will have to list all such prime numbers having a difference of 2 in between?  How to go ahead when X is odd and Y even ?

Comment: These are the same triples (in a different order).  If $X$ is odd and $Y=2$ then $X, X-2$ must be a twin prime pair.   Thus you might have $(13,11,2)$ or $(13,2,11)$ for $(X,Y,X-Y)$.

Comment: (X,2,X-2) and (X,Y,2) , how are they same ?

Comment: I gave you an explicit example.  Remember, you are only asked to count the possible values of $X$, not the number of triples.

Comment: Can this be solved by the knowledge of representing prime number in the form of 6k+1 or 6k-1 form , where k is a natural number.  Like what I was thinking to first take the case when X=6k+1, Y=6m+1 , so X-Y=6(k-m) , but prime cant be multiple of 6 , then I took X=6k-1 and Y=6m-1 , again this is not possible , and then can check for X=6k+1, Y=6m-1 and X=6k-1, Y=6m+1 ?

Comment: None of that seems at all relevant.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:**
For any prime number $X$, there exists a prime number $Y$ such that $X-Y$ is prime if and only if $X-2$ is prime.

*Proof.* If $X$ is such a prime number, then $X$ is a sum of two prime numbers because
$$X=Y+(X-Y).$$
Of course $X$ is odd because $X$ is prime and greater than $2$. So either $Y$ is even or $X-Y$ is even. The only even prime is $2$, so either $Y=2$ or $X-Y=2$. In either case $X-2$ is prime.

Conversely, if $X-2$ is prime then there exists a prime number $Y$ such that $X-Y$ is prime; simply take $Y=2$.

---

In view of this claim, it suffices to count the number of primes $X<50$ for which $X-2$ is also prime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not able to understand the converse condition, could you elaborate that a bit

Comment: @Fin27 I have rewritten my answer to be a bit clearer. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: for converse relation , will we write it as (X-2)=(Y-2)+(X-Y) and then form 2 cases as done earlier ? (X-2) is odd, so either X-Y is even or Y-2 is even ?